# C# checkbox log file write

Tags: c#, checkbox, cmd, ping

I tried to do checkbox to write a log if checkbox is checked.

But i got so many problems so i didnt know what to do next i messed up code.

If you look image there is checkbox to write a log and if i check it and enter IP address and then clicking "Ping!" button then must be ping and sametime writing a log file to c:\Logs\ .

[image]

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;

namespace PingProgramm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Thread th;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(checkBox1.Checked)
            {

            }
            th = new Thread(thread1);
            th.Start();
        }

        public void thread1()
        {
            try
            {
                string command = "/c ping -t " + textBox1.Text;
                ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD", command);
                Process proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
                procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                procStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_OutputDataReceived);
                proc.Start();
                proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
                proc.WaitForExit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //if an error occurs with in the try block, it will handled here.
            }
        }
        void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (stop)
            {
                var proc = (Process)sender;

                stop = false; // allows you to spawn a new thread after stopping the first
                proc.SynchronizingObject = this; // puts the form in charge of async communication
                proc.Kill(); // terminates the thread
                proc.WaitForExit(); // thread is killed asynchronously, so this goes here...

            }
            if (e.Data != null)
            {
                string newLine = e.Data.Trim() + Environment.NewLine;
                MethodInvoker append = () => richTextBox1.Text += newLine;
                richTextBox1.BeginInvoke(append);
            }
        }
        bool firstTime = true;
        private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (firstTime)
            {
                firstTime = false;
                textBox1.Clear();
            }
        }

        bool stop = false;
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stop = true;
        }

        public static void WriteLog(string strLog)
        {
            StreamWriter log;
            FileStream fileStream = null;
            DirectoryInfo logDirInfo = null;
            FileInfo logFileInfo;

            string logFilePath = "C:\\Logs\\";
            logFilePath = logFilePath + "Log-" + System.DateTime.Today.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "." + "txt";
            logFileInfo = new FileInfo(logFilePath);
            logDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(logFileInfo.DirectoryName);
            if (!logDirInfo.Exists) logDirInfo.Create();
            if (!logFileInfo.Exists)
            {
                fileStream = logFileInfo.Create();
            }
            else
            {
                fileStream = new FileStream(logFilePath, FileMode.Append);
            }
            log = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
            log.WriteLine(strLog);
            log.Close();
        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

And if I click "Stop!" button then it stops pinging + stops writing a log.

Best wishes,

KLDesigns

Comment: Did u tried to debug? Where is your code failing with what exception ?

Comment: It doesnt say something wrong or something but my method somehow not working if i try it.

Comment: Do you know how to debug your code? What about Exception handling ? No one can help you unless you are not willing to yourself

Comment: "not working" is a too vague description. You need to specify a little. Is it not pinging?, is it not writing the log? is it not reacting to your checkbox? is it something else?

Comment: where are you calling WriteLog?

Comment: Ping working, but its not writing log if i click checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
MethodInvoker append = () => richTextBox1.Text += newLine;
```

To

```
MethodInvoker append = () => {
        richTextBox1.Text += newLine;
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            WriteLog(newLine);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Error CS0103 The name 'WriteLine' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Sorry that should have said WriteLog, answer updated